# sqlcmd.exe works locally but not through azure pipelines

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sqlcmd

I am attempting to get an old script running in azure pipelines, the script is quite old but it works great when ran locally. However, when I execute the script through Azure Pipelines it comes back with an error.

The environment the self-hosted agent is running on is a Windows Server 2012 R2 device with PowerShell 5.1. In an attempt at simplicity, I have reduced much of the code into a much smaller version for easier replication.

##### Original Formatting

**Local:** Works  - **Pipeline:** Fails

```
$sql = "SELECT @@Version"
$sql | sqlcmd -S $server -U $username -P $env:PASSWORD_ENV -l 30 -d "master" -I -b -h -1 -W -j 2>&1
```

##### Parameter Formatting

**Local:** Works  - **Pipeline:** Works

```
$sql = "SELECT @@Version"
sqlcmd -Q $sql -S $server -U $username -P $env:PASSWORD_ENV -l 30 -d "master" -I -b -h -1 -W -j 2>&1
```

The error this command outputs is

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Could not find stored procedure 'master.dbo.﻿SELECT'.

Now one might say,

> Well just update the scripts to use the parameter method!

Which is a valid argument, although these scripts are quite old, and it isn't only this command that is running into issues. There is some kind of environment issue when ran through pipelines that is causing a more wide spread issue. If I install the latest version of PowerShell and check the box for `pwsh` the command works, however it fails elsewhere as the scripts use commands for WMI which was replaced for Get-CIMInstance in later versions. But again... all the original scripts work when ran locally without issue.

##### Environment

- SQLCMD (local): 13.0.1601.5
- SQLCMD (pipeline): 13.0.1601.5
- PSVersion (local): 5.1.14409.1005
- PSVersion (pipeline): 5.1.14409.1005